# How to write this succinctly?

Tags: r

Can someone please show me the short way of writing the following lines of R code:

```
    core_ts0 <- coredata(ts0)
    core_ts1 <- coredata(ts1)
    core_ts2 <- coredata(ts2)
    core_ts3 <- coredata(ts3)
    core_ts4 <- coredata(ts4)
    core_ts5 <- coredata(ts5)
```

Comment: What are ts0, ts1, ...? Are these objects? How do you have them stored?

Comment: They are time series (at daily intervals). They are xts objects.
Used library(xts).

In general, I have several instances where I have to write a large number of similar lines like this, and I was hoping there's a way of writing a loop. In this example, to loop between 0 and 5.

Comment: Do you already have these objects when you want to store them into core_ts objects? Or can you combine the two, create the ts objects and at the same time store them into a new object?

Comment: I already have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
lst=list()

for (i in 0:5) {
    lst[[paste0("core_ts",i)]]=coredata(get(paste0("ts",i)))
}

list2env(lst,envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the sort of solution I wanted!
As you can tell, I'm new to R. Can you please explain the last line? I can't tell what it's doing there. I mean this:
list2env(lst,envir=.GlobalEnv)

Comment: @MarizaCosta-Cabral You can check the help pages for more information `From a named list x, create an environment containing all list components as objects, or “multi-assign” from x into a pre-existing environment.`, in other words it breaks all the list elements into objects and saves them into your environment.